# dokku + postgres : "the scheme postgres does not accept registry part"

Tags: postgresql, dokku

I'm trying to run dokku on DigitalOcean to get a ruby/rails project up with postgres.

I got help to finding the logs, but I'm at loss when I see this :

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize': the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: root:aLZgAlQKbHbKhHHn@: (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

any ideas on what I could perhaps look into?
the domain name is fritida.se the databasename i fritida (or was it fritida.se?)

I'm going to go and look for a way to list databases.

Comment: Nope, I switched to mysql, and then that worked. But then I was never able to setup more than one rails app on Digital Ocean, after spending more time than it was worth, I gave up and tried to learn Phoenix (Elixir) instead ^^'

Comment: It's possible the hostname wasn't set. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64344976/27358).

Answer (score 0):

## if your password contains unsafe characters

Connection string used for `DATABASE_URL` cannot contain special characters (anything other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_~-\.]`, e.g. `@` is a common one to mess up). Solution is to url-encode.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280541/1733117