# `initialize': the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: postgres:@ (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError) with Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, docker

I'm using Rails with Postgres DB Docker container attached. It looks like I'm getting below error when I run `rails c`:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:204:in `initialize': the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: postgres:@ (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Is there a reason why this isn't working?

My `database.yml` is:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

`$DATABASE_URL` is defined

Interestingly it was working for a few days until yesterday and stopped working again today.

Below is what Rails 4.2.1 generates!

```
# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Why on earth would they recommend env variable that is reserved!?

> **UPDATE**: Actually this is still not fixed. It looks like environment variable is not being picked up from `database.yml` file when running `rails runner` which is run by cron task to invoke Sidekiq worker job (using Whenever). I had to put `url:` static value instead to get it working for now but given that `docker` ip changes every time its run from the image I would prefer `rails runner` to pick up environment variables properly. This may be related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19256#issuecomment-102980786 but the solution didn't work either.

Comment: This is missing a lot of debug information. What is `$DATABASE_URL` set to? What is running as a container, Rails and PostgreSQL or just PostgreSQL? At first glance, it seems like you are misunderstanding the `database.yml` file. It should be the file OR `$DATABASE_URL`. `$DATABASE_URL` is interpreted by Rails itself, you don't re-use it in the `database.yml`.

Comment: @AndyShinn see below answer. Apparently $DATABASE_URL is reserved by Rails which means when I'm running it already I cannot run `rails c` again if you understand what I mean

Comment: It isn't that it is reserved, it is an alternative to `database.yml`. If you remove that particular environment from the `database.yml` you can set `DATABASE_URL` as an environment variable and then run Rails operations without needing sensitive credentials in source.

Comment: @AndyShinn I don't think any application doesn't have production environment. Not to mention wouldn't you want to have at least development, test, staging and production environments separately?

Comment: My point was, you can use `DATABASE_URL` in production (overriding the `database.yml`) and still use `database.yml` for test and staging.

Comment: Following the advice in the answer of @david-moles, it starts working for me just encoding the URL. (URL Encode)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rename your environment variable!

`DATABASE_URL` is reserved by Rails, and interpreted by ActiveRecord itself.  I ran into the same issue.

Instead, use something like this:

```
    host:     <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
    password: <%= ENV['DB_PWD'] %>
```

Comment: This is really crazy. DATABASE_URL is generated by Rails! See my above update

Comment: Actually this is still not fixed. It looks like environment variable is not being picked up from `database.yml` file when running `rails runner` which is run by cron task to invoke Sidekiq worker job

Comment: you need to make sure that it's actually set in the environment for the user which runs the Rails process -- e.g. `printenv` on the command line, or in the Rails console: `puts ENV.inspect`

Comment: This is what I run from crontab `0 13 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /sites/backend/releases/20151231032057 && bin/rails runner -e production '\''ReminderWorker.perform_async'\'' >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1'` I tried `/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /sites/backend/releases/20151231032057 && printenv'` and it gives me with corrent $DB_URL environment variable. Is there something wrong with `rails runner` ?

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is wrong. There's nothing wrong with using `DATABASE_URL` in your `database.yml`, although [doing so explicitly is probably redundant](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database). The problem is with the value of the URL.

`ActiveRecord` uses `URI::RFC2396_Parser` to parse database URLs. The error message above indicates that it's not able to parse the URL, probably because the hostname is missing, cf.

```rb
URI::RFC2396_Parser.new.parse('postgres://postgres:@/mydb')
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#       1: from (irb):30
# URI::InvalidURIError (the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: postgres:@ (or bad hostname?))
```

Other invalid hostnames, such as hostnames with underscores (common in docker-compose setups) will cause similar errors:

```rb
URI::RFC2396_Parser.new.parse('postgres://postgres:postgres@my_postgres/mydb')
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#        1: from (irb):34
# URI::InvalidURIError (the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: postgres:postgres@my_postgres (or bad hostname?))
```

What can be especially confusing is that `URI.parse()` uses `URI::RFC3986_Parser`, which is much more forgiving, and will accept either of these "bad" URLs.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! All I had to do was to rename the database container from `my_db` to `my-db` and adjust the URL. That's it!

Comment: Wow, thanks for saving me so much of a headache.

Answer (score 7):

From the ["Configuring Rails Applications" guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database), it would appear that `DATABASE_URL` is used for configuring database access. Another way to configure database access is the presence of the file `config/database.yml`. Trying to use both methods to configure database access causes the issue you are facing.

## if your password contains unsafe characters

Connection string used for `DATABASE_URL` cannot contain special characters (anything other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_~-\.]`, e.g. `@` is a common one to mess up). Solution is to url-encode.

## if you are using dokku

- https://github.com/Kloadut/dokku-pg-plugin/issues/76 - Host and Port information are missing
- https://github.com/dokku/dokku-postgres/issues/28 - Rewritten link command generates invalid host

## if you are using pghero

- https://github.com/ankane/pghero - Fail to start if password contain @